# How to get align="center" effect in CSS and be XHTML compliant and have it work on most browsers

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm trying to get some HTML pages to be more compliant and am starting off with simple stuff like removing align="center" in tables, etc.

However, I can't seem to get the effect I want using CSS. Stuff I've tried include

```
text-align:middle
vertical-align:middle
```

and the most suggested by designer friends

```
margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width: 100px
```

But under certain layouts or certain browsers (especially IE6) none seem to work. Is there a reliable way to do this using purely CSS and get it to work on most browsers?

EDIT:
I meant `text-align: center;`. Typed it in a rush. The page already has a DOCTYPE but I'm not sure if it's appropriate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: can you post a live url so we can take a look at that, or at least the HTML and CSS that's required?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's:

```
text-align: center;
```

for horizontal centering but:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

for vertical centering but vertical centering this way will pretty much only work with table cells. To get cross-browser vertical centering without using tables look at [Vertical Centering in CSS](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) (yes it's non-trivial).

**Note:** `text-align: middle` and `vertical-align: center` are incorrect values.

To horizontally center a block element, the usual trick is:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">Some test...</div>
</div>
```

with:

```
#outer { width: 600px; }
#inner { width: 300px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black; }
```

Bear in mind, that this won't necessarily work with certain versions of IE in the euphemistic "quirks" mode. It's a good practice to force IE into (also euphemistic) "standards compliant" mode by using a DOCTYPE at the top of your document.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal auto margins on an block/table element would horizontally center it assuming it's positioned relatively/statically, has explicit or intrinsic width ( example being a table ) and *not* floated with the document in standards mode, though there are minor exceptions.

It might be better to actually provide an example where the element isn't centred.

Answer (score 0):

```
display:block; margin:0px auto;
```

That will center a block inside its parent without centering its content.